# Why can I not set a pre selected value to my select list in HTML with getElementById?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular7, getelementbyid

I am trying to set a pre selected option based on a previous select list (that part is not shown below). It's working with `getelementById()` when I use it on an `<input>` field but not on a `<select>`. Why is that?

Working example:

```
<label for="goalcategory">Edit assigned category</label>
        <select id="selectedGoalcategory" class="form-control" required>
          <option></option>
          <option *ngFor="let goalcategory of allGoalcategories">{{goalcategory.description}}</option>
        </select>

        <input class="input" style="width:10%;" id="TestInput" type="text"/>
```

Typsescript behind it:

```
getCategoriByGoal()
  {
    var preSelectedGoalcategory = this.selectedGoal.goalcategory;

    this.selectedGoalcategory = preSelectedGoalcategory;

    (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("TestInput")).value = 
    this.selectedGoalcategory.description;

  }
```

The way I want it to work (HTML):

```
<label for="goalcategory">Edit assigned category</label>
        <select id="selectedGoalcategory" class="form-control" required>
          <option></option>
          <option *ngFor="let goalcategory of allGoalcategories">{{goalcategory.description}}</option>
        </select>
```

The way I want it to work (Typscript):

```
getCategoryByGoal()
  {
   var preSelectedGoalcategory = this.selectedGoal.goalcategory;

    this.selectedGoalcategory = preSelectedGoalcategory;

    (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("selectedGoalcategory")).value = 
    this.selectedGoalcategory.description;

  }
```

Comment: With two-way binding, there is no need to rely on  .getElementById() for this scenario!

Comment: Ok but how am I then gonna be able to set it to a specific value? I cannot pass it by only using: var preSelectedGoalcategory = this.selectedGoal.goalcategory;

    this.selectedGoalcategory = preSelectedGoalcategory;

Comment: Try to make [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't see any issue with your current method: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agvcsf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

If you dont mind adding 3rd party components, you could add ng-select, it would make your life easier for a lot of things.
Install ng-select from npm:

```
npm install --save @ng-select/ng-select
```

After that add it to your module along with FormsModule:

```
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [NgSelectModule, FormsModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And in your HTML you can use it like this:

```
 <ng-select [items]="allGoalcategories" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id" name="goalcategories"
                        [(ngModel)]="selectedGoalcategory">
 </ng-select>
```

Now every time you change selectedGoalcategory it will reflect in your other dropdown, and you dont need to use getElementById

Answer (score 0):

As @wentjun said, there is no need to rely on document.getElementById() for this scenario.
To get the value of the dropdown you would need to bind the "selectedGoalcategory" to the dropdown and follow below:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedGoalCategory">
  <option></option>
  <option *ngFor="let goalcategory of goalCategories" [value]="goalcategory.id">{{ goalcategory.name }}</option>
</select>
```

So "preselect" a value, you just set the value of "dropDownValue" to one of the values in the dropdown.

I'm not sure why you need the input field, but if you want the input field to reflect the value of the  dropdown, then you would do this:

```
<input class="input" style="width:10%;" id="TestInput" type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedGoalCategory" />
```

Comment: What isn't binding? the input element or the select element?

Comment: The select-element

Comment: How come it binds to the input element but not to the select-element?

Comment: Have you added [(ngModel)]="selectedGoalCategory" to your select dropdown?

Comment: My recommendation would be to follow this: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngmodel---two-way-binding-to-form-elements-with-ngmodel

...it seems you're trying develop with Angular like how you would with a Native JS application.